# android getSpans parameters

Tags: android, parsing, hyperlink

I want to parse a text for some links (url and phone numbers) and I've tried code

```
String message = "text text www.evz.ro test 1234567 test www.220.ro test Http://emm.ro";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(message);
Linkify.addLinks(ss, Linkify.ALL);
Object[] spans = ss.getSpans(0, ss.length() - 1, null)
```

What parameter should I use instead of null? What class type?
I just need to know from where the link starts and where it ends

Answer (score 12, accepted):

found the solution. here it is:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(str);
Linkify.addLinks(spannableString, Linkify.ALL);
URLSpan[] spans = spannableString.getSpans(0, spannableString.length() , URLSpan.class);
```

Comment: Notice that you're using the string.length() here, not string.length()-1. That's just fixed a problem I was having, but it seems to contradict the documentation, which says that second parameter is an end index, not a length. Weird...

Comment: Think like if that index refers to the space between letters.  For example: the string 'abc' has 4 spaces (|a|b|c|).  That spaces are numbered from 0 to 3, so the index of the final one match with the spannableString length (value 3 refering to the 4th element).

Comment: I think `getSpans` is inefficient for this use case, so you might want to try `nextSpanTransition` instead. Here, might be useful: https://youtu.be/x-FcOX6ErdI?t=749 .